# get position of new fragment when scroll view pager

Tags: android-viewpager

I'm using ViewPager in my app and define it in the main Activity. Inside onCreate method I load some number of pages from SharedPreferences and then pass it to PagerAdapter:

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass them to your PagerAdapter's constructor, when you set adapter.